# Is there any information about this acoustic Ibanez artist model 2600 (70's) from my late father?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

While cleaning the house I came across an old **acoustic Ibanez model 2600** that used to be my fathers guitar. Now finding any good info on this guitar with google and duckduckgogo searches was fruitless except for some info without credible sources.

[Guitardaterproject](https://www.guitardaterproject.org/ibanez.aspx) (as suggested by @b3ko could unfortunately not help me any further and many other serial number sites came up empty so it must mean this guitar is from before 1974.

I even searched old Ibanez catalogues online but they all started at model 2601, when was it build and are there any specs? Its one of the few things left from my father.

I took some pictures that will be displayed below.

I hope someone on this SE knows this Ibanez and can tell me the background of this guitar because I am pretty much stumped on this one. **Is there any information about this acoustic Ibanez artist model 2600 (70's) from my late father?**
Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of info are you looking for? You can probably look up the serial number on line and learn a little something

Comment: Try putting the serial number in here: https://www.guitardaterproject.org/ibanez.aspx

Comment: @b3ko this site does not appear to be working.

Comment: In what way? It works for me.

Comment: I fixed it by using a VPN and setting my location to America, the serial number is not recognized though.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.vintagejapanguitars.com.br/en/ibanez-1978-acoustics-catalogue/, it seems to be a model that was available in 1978:

[image]

The headstock is not the same. I wonder if the headstock on yours may be a replacement? The inlay on it looks a little 'homebrew' to my eyes. (Though the distinctive shape at the top is the same as that in the picture...)

Another example is https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?finnkode=27299035.

A similar model is mentioned at http://www.ibanezcollectors.com/discus/messages/11/19699.html?1163455138.

Comment: *The headstock is not the same* It looks like it is the same headstock, just it's been refinished (or possibly had the faceplate removed or sanded off).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is a genuine Ibanez, or something else with a fake label.

As the OP discovered, the "2600 series" of models seems to start with model 2601. Also, none of the 260x models have a cutout in the body like the OP's picture - see the vintage catalogs scanned [here](http://s93105080.onlinehome.us/Ibanez-Catalogs/).

I suppose one possibility is that it was a design that never went into commercial production, but your father acquired it somehow.

Comment: This model 2605 from 1978 has the same logo on the label inside the body (even though the better known logo is on the headstock). https://reverb.com/item/24580914-ibanez-artist-2605-1978

Comment: http://www.ibanezcollectors.com/discus/messages/11/19699.html?1163455138 mentions a 2600 cutaway....

Answer (score 0):

Нет войне has answered the question, and correctly identified Dad's guitar as an Artist Model 2600 (Factory code DM788) from 1978.
The 1978 catalog describes it as a Jumbo with a cutaway.
https://ibanez.fandom.com/wiki/1978_catalogs

And dwizum and Нет войне correctly surmised that the original headstock logo was sanded off, and the curious, personalized inlay was installed. The face of the headstock was then re-varnished.

Quite an object of very personal value to the family, but wouldn't fetch much money elsewhere.